# how to set access control or privilege for Django models and views?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

i create a model for website/ frontend . i have 3 types of users. only 1 type i want to see the frontend model. how to create a dynamic access control for the django frontends. please give some solutuion or suggest a plugin. Thanks for solution in advance.

Comment: Please look thought Django permissions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Comment: can you please suggest any demo or sample code from other than official document or any 3rd party sites?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the template or views side.

Assuming your preferred user type is 'student', you do this:


**Template**

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_student %}
*content*
{% endif %}
```

Or this:


**Views**

Assuming you want to restrict the details of a blog post to only students, you need to create a condition right after defining the 'post_detail_view' view function.

```
def post_detail_view(request):
    if not request.user.is_student:
        **do something (eg. raise 404 or httpresponse or redirect)**
    **code for this view goes here**
```

Declaring the restriction in the view allows you to do more than just restrict the content. You can raise a 404 error, redirect the unauthorized user and more. The template solution simply lets you restrict the content.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I also did like this. but what i want is dynamic access control. The above code is static.

Comment: @HariharanAR could you please be more specific or give examples of some sites or apps that have the feature you want